# Cannot apply media queries via style sheet for different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

So I'm trying to make my website as responsive as possible but for some weird reason, I cannot apply an alternative stylesheet to my homepage via media queries for a different screen resolution.

let me explain, my homepage consists of a slideshow done in javascript however when a smaller resolution is used, the images are too big so I want to put some alternative content there using a different css sheet. I tried doing it on my other pages and it worked like a charm (note that there is no javascript within the other pages). I assume that maybe the javascript code is preventing the alternative stylesheet from loading. More specifically, I want the slideshow to show up only on 1920x1080 resolutions, on other resolutions I want other content. Sorry for the long question, I hope I'm making sense. Here is the html from my homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="description" content="Affordable and professional web design">
  <meta name="keywords" content="web design, affordable web design, 
 professional web design">
<meta name="author" content="#">
<title>Light Designs | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1366px)" 
href="index/res.css"/>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('body,html').css("overflow","hidden");-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
 <div class="container">
   <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="index/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
 </a></h1>
   <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">home</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="services.html">services</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>  
</header>

  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="slide"><img src="index/showcase.png" alt="#"/></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="index/pic4.png" alt="#"/></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="index/pic3.png" alt="#"/></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="index/pic5.png" alt="#"/></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="index/pic4.png" alt="#"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(new Date());
 }, 1000);
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {

    //configuration
    var width = 1920
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 4000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    //cache DOM
    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, 
  function(){
          currentSlide++;
          if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 1;
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
    });
  }, pause);
}        
  function stopSlider() {
      clearInterval(interval);
  }

  $slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

  startSlider();
});
</script>

<section id="newsletter">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h1>
    <form>
      <input class="emailBox_1" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
      <button class="button_1" type="submit" class="button_1">
    <span>Subscribe</span></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
   <p>Light designs, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
</footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here's the css

```
 body {
font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #0099ff;
width: 100%;
}

/* Global */
 div.container {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

 header {
 background: #35424a;
 color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 0px;
max-height: 70px;
 height: 50%;
 border-bottom: #0099ff 4.5px solid;
 color: white;
 }

#logo {
float: left;
position: relative;
bottom: 30px;
}

nav {
float: right;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
right: 60px;
color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 nav li {
 display: inline;
}

a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;

}

a:hover {
color: #0099ff;
}

header .current a{
color: #0099ff;
font-weight:bold;
}

.slider {
width: 1920px;
height: 780px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slides {
 display: block;
 width: 9600px;
 height: 780px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.slider .slide {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
 width: 1920px;
height: 780px;
}

 #newsletter{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 10px;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #35424a; 
}

#newsletter form {
float:right;
margin-top: 7px;
position: relative;
bottom: 8px; 
} 

#newsletter h1{
margin-bottom: 0px;
float:left;
position: relative;
bottom: 5px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"]{
padding:4px;
height:25px;
width:250px;
}


.button_1 {
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #0099ff;
border: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 4px;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 20px;
padding-top: 18px;
padding-bottom: -2;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
transition: all 1s;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 5px;
position: relative;
top: 4px;
}

.button_1 span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.button_1 span:after {
content: '\00bb';
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
right: -20px;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.button_1:hover span {
 padding-right: 25px;
}

.button_1:hover span:after {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 0;
}

footer{
background-color:#0099ff;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 10px;
 height: 20px;
  }

 footer p {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 6px;
}
```

Comment: use <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: There does not appear to be any code to determine the user's screen size, unless I missed it.

Comment: Whats the purpose of the '*' after your link tag?

Comment: The * is just a mistake I did while copying the code, it's not in the actual code though

Comment: @Mark Stewart this is the piece of code that specifies screen size if I'm not mistaken <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1366px)" 
href="index/res.css"/>

Comment: @mlegg I tried adding it, no luck, thanks for trying

Comment: Are you able to show a codepen or something simular of the issue? Your code looks ok to me; it should be calling res.css on all screens below 1366px width. And I can't see anything obvious in the JS that would be blocking that extra CSS call.

As a side note, it's more common practice to use media queries within the CSS itself, rather than call separate files, because generally speaking, an extra http request is more expensive than a few more bytes of CSS in one file.

Comment: media= with those parameters may be not well supported;  I looked at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp  - it says min-width and max-width are deprecated. I tried using min-width and that seemed to work so you could reverse your logic.

Comment: Wow, guys, I'm really lost for words, I've tried calling it from multiple different locations, from the html head and from the css sheet via the @url rule, still no luck. I'll tinker around with it all night if I have to, but I'll make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a media query (placing it after .slider) to hide the slider container:

```
@media (max-width: 1919px) {
  .slider {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm although I could swear I tried this earlier and it didn't work. The important thing is, it works now, thank you so much.